# JS reducer: return combined array of objects

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have such two arrays of objects:

```
const first = [{text: 'sometext1', applicable: true}, {text: 'sometext2', applicable: false}, {text: 'sometext3', applicable: true}];

const second = [{text: 'sometext1', applicable: true}, {text: 'sometext2', applicable: true}];
```

As a result I want to get such array:

```
const result = [{text: 'sometext1', applicable: true}, {text: 'sometext2', applicable: true}, {text: 'sometext3', applicable: true}];
```

so => just add to second array all non-existing items from first array, filtered by 'text' key.

is it possible to do via reducers? or maybe any better way?

Answer (score 1):

Just iterate over first array and check whether each item present in second array or not, if not present then push in to second array.

```
first.forEach((item) => {
    const index = second.findIndex((st) => st.text === item.text);
    if(index < 0) {
        second.push(item);
    }
})
```

Comment: it's a dirty way :)

Comment: Map we can't use, as it'll return new array. Even if we use reduce on 'first' array and pass 'second' array as accumulator,  you have to check each element is present in second array or not.

Comment: How about, first iterating over 'second' and storing text's in map, then iterate over 'first' array and check each item is present in map or not and then push. Which will avoid finding of elements every time. We need to traverse each array once. So complexity also less.

Answer (score 0):

You can use maps

```js
const first = [{text: 'sometext1', applicable: true}, {text: 'sometext2', applicable: false}, {text: 'sometext3', applicable: true}];

const second = [{text: 'sometext1', applicable: true}, {text: 'sometext2', applicable: true}];

var a=second.map((e)=>e.text);
first.map((e)=>{a.includes(e.text)?false:second.push(e)})
console.log(second);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a filter to remove duplicates using a key.

```
function concatAndRemoveDuplicates(arr1, arr2) {
  return arr1.concat(
    arr2.filter((o) => !arr2.map((x) => x.text).includes(o.text)),
  );
}
```

Comment: wrong, it should pick up all items like in my result, your solution will set second item with `false` applicable

Answer (score 0):

As per your tags, I see that you have the possibility to use ES6 so you could do it with [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) for example to have unique values in your array and then filter it:

```
const grouped = [...second, ...first];
const result = 
   [ ...new Set(grouped.map(({ text}) => text))]
   .map(text => grouped.find(obj => obj.text === text))
```

### Tests

Here is a [link with tests](https://codesandbox.io/s/9l57wz68ky):
[image]

Comment: not sure that it's working for 100% cases, sometimes it's taking wrong object, so `applicable` value is ovewrriten from `first` - what is wrong

Comment: probably due to sorting order

Comment: @brabertaser19 Could you confirm it with examples?
I will update the answer with tests. Please feel free to add your tests and point the issue

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```js
const first = [{text: 'sometext1', applicable: true}, {text: 'sometext2', applicable: false}, {text: 'sometext3', applicable: true}];

const second = [{text: 'sometext1', applicable: true}, {text: 'sometext2', applicable: true}];

const results = [...second, ...first.filter(({text:firstText})=>!second.find(({text})=>text===firstText))]

console.log(results);
```

but it does not clone the objects.